# PrimeFaces open dialog several times with rendered attribute

Tags: primefaces, dialog, javabeans

I try to implement a dialog box accessible everywhere in my project and I was wondering if this solution is possible.

The dialog is included in the template of my project. For example, where I am on the login page, I would like to show the dialog when the button "Login" is clicked and the authentication is successful. So I catch the bean linked to the dialog with:

getFacesContext().getELContext().getELResolver().getValue(getFacesContext().getELContext(), null, beanName);

and I set the "show" argument. (have a look below)

The first time, it's working. When I access the login page, the dialog is not rendered and when I click the button login, the attribute show is set, the page is updated and the dialog appears. But if I close it, I could not fire it again when I click again the button. (The dialog is rendered but not shown)

My dialog is like this (I have visible="true" cause I want to show each time it's rendered):

```
<h:form>
    <p:dialog header="Dialog" widgetVar="myDialog" rendered="#{bean.show}" visible="true">
        <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{bean.onClose}" />
        ...
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

The bean is in viewscope:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {

    private boolean show; // + Getters and Setters

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.show = false;
        ...
    }

    public void onClose() {
        this.show = false;
    }

}
```

And I can add that my LoginBean which is setting the show argument is in viewScope too.

Thanks